# Jest unit test for angular custom validation to select atleast one control in formgroup

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, angular-validation, angular-custom-validators

I'm writing a unit test with **jest** cases for angular custom validator which is user must select atleast one filter in formgroup. I'm new to angular unit test. Please let me know what I have missed?

**Error:**

```
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function
Received has type:  function
Received has value: [Function anonymous]
```

**custom.validator.ts**

```
export const atLeastOne =
  (validator: ValidatorFn) =>
  (group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {

    const hasAtLeastOne =
      group &&
      group.controls &&
      Object.keys(group.controls).some((k) => !validator(group.controls[k]));

    return hasAtLeastOne ? null : { atLeastOne: true };
  };
```

**custom.validator.spec.ts**

```
describe("atLeastOne()", () => {
  it("should return true if no filter is selected", () => {
    const mockValidator = jest.fn();
    const mockForm = {
      controls: {
        assetsClassesControl: "Object",
        riskControl: "Object",
      },
      errors: {
        atLeastOne: true,
      },
      status: "INVALID",
      pristine: true,
    };
    expect(atLeastOne(mockValidator)).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

**app.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.filterForm.setValidators(atLeastOne(Validators.required));
}
```